# PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment: - shapely

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to remove shapely in anaconda using:

```
conda remove shapely
```

but receiving the following warning message:

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
 - shapely
```

When I suspect the target package is already uninstalled, I use the following command:

```
conda list
```

It shows that shapely package is still in target environment:

```
shapely                   2.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
```

How should I clean up the warning message? Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

please use

```
conda uninstall shapely
```

Comment: Run the suggested coding: 
    
    conda uninstall shapely

but still receive the error message:

    Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
    Solving environment: failed

    PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
      - shapely

Comment: is your conda env active ,are you in the right conda environment ?

Comment: Using Python 3.10.11
a) Sequence of Installation of packages :
1) (base) C:\Users\W>conda install -c conda-forge shapely => successful installed in anaconda ;
2) (base) C:\Users\W>conda install -c conda-forge scikit-fem => successful installed in anaconda ;
3) %pip install femwell => successful installed in Juypter notebook but start to receive warning message: WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -hapely (c:\users\w\anaconda3\lib\site-packages) ;

Comment: b) Uninstallation of shapely : conda uninstall shapely
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done 
Solving environment: failed 
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment: - shapely

Comment: if you want to remove unused packages and cache , try using `conda clean --all`

Comment: conda clean --all : Remove index cache, lock files, unused cache packages, tarballs, and logfiles. Will this command break dependency of other packages?

Comment: already tried     conda clean --all     but problem is still there